# Sort questions by most recently answered

Tags: feature-request, questions, sorting

One can sort questions by the newest question ("newest") or by the most recent activity ("active"), but there is no way to sort by most recently answered.  I would like to request this sort option be added.

"Active" sort of does the job, but not so well if there are lots of new questions and/or edited posts coming in.  Sometimes, I would like to review only new answers, not everything else, and there is no way to easily do that at current.

Comment: @PolyGeo I see the "duplicate" was asked by you - why not go ahead and change it into a feature request then instead of simply saying it "could/should" be done?

Comment: I just changed it.  My reluctance was my recollection that I originally proposed it as a feature request and it went to a -5 or -6 vote in no time.  After refinement and changing to a support request it climbed slowly back into positive territory.